# paired t-test shows no difference between median and Wilcoxon test p value shows that there is a difference between median values ? How to interpret?

Tags: ranking, descriptive-statistics, experiments, interpretation

I have a dataset. I wanted to do paired t test on it. So I carried out normality test and it showed that it does not follow normal distribution. So I used Wilcoxon test in place of paired t test. The descriptive statistics of my data shows median value of 0 but when I ran wilcoxon test, it gave me a p value <0.05 stating to reject null. Could you please tell me why this discrepancy in my test results?

**summary(Rel)**
REL1.                REL2.          Diff
Min.   :1.000     Min.   :1.000    Min.   :-5.0000
1st Qu.:7.000     1st Qu.:6.000    1st Qu.:-1.0000
Median :7.000     Median :7.000    Median : 0.0000
Mean   :6.617     Mean   :6.289    Mean   :-0.3282
3rd Qu.:7.000     3rd Qu.:7.000    3rd Qu.: 0.0000
Max.   :7.000     Max.   :7.000    Max.   : 3.0000

**Wilcoxon signed rank test**
data:  REL1. and REL2.
V = 7993.5, p-value = 2.449e-13
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

Comment: Have you removed information on missing values by any chance? Descriptives run on each variable separately. Wilcoxon test runs only on the observations which are non-missing for both variables at the same time.

Comment: yes.. I have removed missing values. The above output is after removing missing values only.

Comment: paired t-test does not require normality i.e. normal distribution. You may indicate part of sample data to get a valid response. what is your hypothesis ?